# Exporting Excel getting this error Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I'm using Maatwebsite Laravel Excel package 3.0.
This is my InvoicesExport.php

```
    class InvoicesExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        $company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
         $assets = Asset::where('id', $company_id)->get()->toArray();    
         $assets_array = array();
        if(!$assets->isEmpty()){
         foreach($assets as $asset){
             $assets_array[] = array(
             'Asset ID' => $asset->id,
             'Asset Name' => $asset->name,
             'Description' => $asset->description,
             'Serial Number' => $asset->serialno,
             'External ID' => $asset->external_id,
             'Location' => $asset->location,
             'Expiry Date' => $asset->expiry_date,
             'Owner' => $asset->owner,
             'Status' => $asset->status,
             'Updated at' => $asset->updated_at
             );
            }
        }
        //dd($assets_array); 
        return $assets_array;
    }
}
```

And i keep getting this error

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
```

And this is my function in controller

```
public function excel() 
    {    
          return Excel::download(new InvoicesExport, 'invoices.xlsx');
    }
```

My code looks like this now and I keep getting this error.

```
Call to a member function each() on array
```

**When i use dd($assets_array) I get those 2 items that i have in database, so i think maybe it's problem in my RETURN**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, the problem is outside of the **InvoicesExport** Class.

Why don't you change the type of return?

instead of returning

```
return $assets_array;
```

Do it like this:

```
return collect($assets_array);
```

Comment: You sir, are my HERO! Thanks a lot <3

Comment: `$assets = Asset::where('id', $company_id)->get()->toArray(); ` This line still doesn't work. I only get first asset from table.

Comment: How many records do you have in that table that has id = $company_id? If you have only one, you are going to get one.

Answer (score 0):

you convert the collection to array and try to access it as object 
  just remove the toArray

```
    $assets = Asset::where('id', $company_id)->get();
```

Comment: After changing everything like that i get this error `Call to a member function each() on array`

Comment: just remove toarray   from this   $assets = Asset::where('id', $company_id)->get()->toArray();

Comment: I did, it's still same.

Comment: return your code as  it was and just remove the toarray

Comment: are you return the code as it was and remove the to array?

Comment: Yes sir, I put everything back and just removed toArray(), and it's still same.

Comment: check if the $assets has data by make dd($assets);

Comment: `Call to a member function each() on array`

Comment: put the foreach inside if(!$assets->isEmpty())

Comment: I got this `Collection {#965 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▶]
}`

Comment: I got this again `Call to a member function each() on array
`